# Abstract keyword in front of a class: to be or not to be

Tags: c#, .net

Should I always annotate a class which has only protected constructors by design with `abstract` keyword? Why?

Let’s suppose the class does not have abstract members.

If no, could you give some examples?

Comment: Try reading about a certain topic before asking silly questions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A type with only protected constructors is still creatable - either through a static factory method on the type, or via reflection (including, as one option, totally skipping the constructors).

An abstract type is **never** creatable.

Mark the type as abstract: *if it is abstract*. So: does it make sense for an object of that type (rather than a subclass) to exist?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not do this by design since thats not what `abstract` classes are made for.

[abstract on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, an abstract class is used to represent a bunch of classes which are of same type in logical view. It means that this bunch of classes are common in either properties or behaviours. It is not used to represent the class which has a 'Private' constructor and can not be created outside the class itself.

Comment: You don't have to have an opinion, there's an article describing what an abstract class is, the same as @Mihai linked to in the comment on the original question, [abstract (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: The description here also fits "interface" and "base class" - I thing in this is specific to abstract, and the key features of abstract are (IMO) missing from the description here.